# Change the tick label of x axis

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I want the ticks displayed on xaxis to have value of y-axis(only value should be changed, and not the position). Below is the JsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/sonal215/337afs1h/1/

Rather than 1, 2 being shown on the x axis, i want 10, 5(respective yaxis values) to be shown on the x axis tick label.

I tried debugging it, there is a class jqplot-xaxis-tick in the library which sets the ticks value.

```
<div class="jqplot-axis jqplot-xaxis" style="position: absolute; width: 180px; height: 18px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><div class="jqplot-xaxis-tick" style="position: absolute; left: 47px;">1</div><div class="jqplot-xaxis-tick" style="position: absolute; left: 127px;">2</div></div>
```

If i can any way change the logic of displaying the values in the library, then it will work.
Or is there any other way to do it.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the `jqplot-xaxis-tick` divs after they are created, and assign them the `y` values from your `s1` data array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s1 = [
    [1, 10],
    [2, 5]
  ];
  plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
    seriesColors: ["#EB2300", "#FFCC00"],
    seriesDefaults: {
      renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
      rendererOptions: {
        varyBarColor: true,
        barWidth: 30,
        barMargin: -30
      },
      pointLabels: {
        show: true
      }
    },
    grid: {
      drawBorder: false
    },
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
      },
      yaxis: {
        tickOptions: {
          show: false
        },
        rendererOptions: {
          drawBaseline: false
        }
      }
    }
  });
 //assign x values with y values//
 $('.jqplot-xaxis-tick').each(function(i,elem) {
        $(this).text(s1[i][1]);
    });
});
```

See a working example in your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/337afs1h/2/

Comment: your solution works perfectly fine for me, thanks. Also i tried doing the following-- var s1 = [['10', 1], ['5', 5]];, this also serves my purpose,            but i guess your solution is more appropriate. Thanks again